# Nginx Net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING when trying to show large JSON

Tags: php, json, nginx, docker, administration

Hello I am trying to show large json using php but when **JSON** file is large I get `Net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING` and see

> "/var/lib/nginx/fastcgi/1/00/0000000001" failed (13: Permission
>   denied) while reading upstream

in my nginx log.

My nginx server starts as from www-data user.

```
ps aux | grep nginx
root         1  0.0  0.0  95592  8872 ?        Ss   12:08   0:00 nginx: master process nginx -g daemon off;
www-data     7  0.0  0.0  95592  3868 ?        S    12:08   0:00 nginx: worker process
www-data     8  0.0  0.0  95592  3868 ?        S    12:08   0:00 nginx: worker process
www-data     9  0.0  0.0  95592  3868 ?        S    12:08   0:00 nginx: worker process
www-data    10  0.0  0.0  95960  5600 ?        S    12:08   0:00 nginx: worker process
www-data    11  0.0  0.0  95592  3868 ?        S    12:08   0:00 nginx: worker process
www-data    12  0.0  0.0  95592  3868 ?        S    12:08   0:00 nginx: worker process
www-data    13  0.0  0.0  95592  3868 ?        S    12:08   0:00 nginx: worker process
www-data    14  0.0  0.0  95592  3868 ?        S    12:08   0:00 nginx: worker process
www-data    15  0.0  0.0  95592  3868 ?        S    12:08   0:00 nginx: worker process
www-data    16  0.0  0.0  95592  3868 ?        S    12:08   0:00 nginx: worker process
www-data    17  0.0  0.0  95592  3868 ?        S    12:08   0:00 nginx: worker process
www-data    18  0.0  0.0  95592  3868 ?        S    12:08   0:00 nginx: worker process
www-data    19  0.0  0.0  95592  3868 ?        S    12:08   0:00 nginx: worker process
www-data    20  0.0  0.0  95592  3868 ?        S    12:08   0:00 nginx: worker process
www-data    21  0.0  0.0  95592  3868 ?        S    12:08   0:00 nginx: worker process
www-data    22  0.0  0.0  95592  3868 ?        S    12:08   0:00 nginx: worker process
www-data    23  0.0  0.0  95592  3868 ?        S    12:08   0:00 nginx: worker process
www-data    24  0.0  0.0  95592  3868 ?        S    12:08   0:00 nginx: worker process
www-data    25  0.0  0.0  95592  3868 ?        S    12:08   0:00 nginx: worker process
www-data    26  0.0  0.0  95592  3868 ?        S    12:08   0:00 nginx: worker process
www-data    27  0.0  0.0  95592  3868 ?        S    12:08   0:00 nginx: worker process
www-data    28  0.0  0.0  95592  3868 ?        S    12:08   0:00 nginx: worker process
www-data    29  0.0  0.0  95592  3868 ?        S    12:08   0:00 nginx: worker process
www-data    30  0.0  0.0  95592  3868 ?        S    12:08   0:00 nginx: worker process
www-data    31  0.0  0.0  95592  3868 ?        S    12:08   0:00 nginx: worker process
www-data    32  0.0  0.0  95592  3868 ?        S    12:08   0:00 nginx: worker process
www-data    33  0.0  0.0  95592  3868 ?        S    12:08   0:00 nginx: worker process
www-data    34  0.0  0.0  95592  3868 ?        S    12:08   0:00 nginx: worker process
www-data    35  0.0  0.0  95592  3868 ?        S    12:08   0:00 nginx: worker process
www-data    36  0.0  0.0  95592  3868 ?        S    12:08   0:00 nginx: worker process
www-data    37  0.0  0.0  95592  3868 ?        S    12:08   0:00 nginx: worker process
www-data    38  0.0  0.0  95592  3868 ?        S    12:08   0:00 nginx: worker process
root        55  0.0  0.0   8868   776 ?        S+   12:14   0:00 grep --color=auto nginx
```

also my php-fpm7 also works form www-data

/var/lib/nginx/ also owned by www-data.

```
ls -l  nginx
total 20
drwxrwxrwx 2 www-data www-data 4096 Aug 21 21:35 body
drwxrwxrwx 2 www-data www-data 4096 Aug 21 21:35 fastcgi
drwxrwxrwx 2 www-data www-data 4096 Aug 21 21:35 proxy
drwxrwxrwx 2 www-data www-data 4096 Aug 21 21:35 scgi
drwxrwxrwx 2 www-data www-data 4096 Aug 21 21:35 uwsgi
```

php memory limit is 512m
nginx body limit is 100m

the server runs usign docker.

My nginx.conf

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 2;
    client_max_body_size 100m;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    server_tokens off;

    server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    log_format main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
             '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
             '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log main;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6].(?!.*SV1)";

    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_min_length 1000;
    gzip_comp_level 6;
    gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    gzip_http_version 1.1;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

Output of stat command

```
stat /var/lib/nginx/fastcgi
  File: '/var/lib/nginx/fastcgi'
  Size: 4096        Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   directory
Device: 40h/64d Inode: 140         Links: 2
Access: (0777/drwxrwxrwx)  Uid: ( 1000/www-data)   Gid: (   33/www-data)
Access: 2016-08-30 11:30:16.268311861 +0000
Modify: 2016-08-21 21:35:34.000000000 +0000
Change: 2016-08-30 11:19:47.711701034 +0000
 Birth: -
```

What can be wrong?

Comment: You are using Chrome? Are you sure that is not a cache related problem?

Comment: Also can you post your OS name and version?

Comment: I use postman for testing requests. I also tried chrome and firefox.

Comment: Debian jessie 8.0

Comment: And you assigned the right perms with `chown -R www-data:www-data /var/lib/nginx`...

Comment: sure you can see the result of ls -l command in the question

Comment: Can you post your `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf ` file?

Comment: Added. See edited post

Comment: Your configuration seems right, that is weird...btw, you can post the output of `stat /var/lib/nginx/fastcgi`

Comment: Added to edited post

Comment: Ok @Sergei...one last step, can you post the content of `php-fpm.conf` to check where `php-fpm.sock` is and run the `stat` command on it ?

Comment: Unfortunately I can not find path to php-fpm.sock I only see such option: listen: 0.0.0.0:9000. however I am able to locatie php7.0-fpm.sock in /var/run/php but php-fpm installation is in another docker container

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally fixed by removing /var/lib/nginx/fastcgi directory and then recreating it from root and changing it's owner to www-data.

now it looks like that

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 www-data root     4096 Sep  5 13:58 fastcgi
```

Also the problem could be fixed by adjusting fastcgi buffer size using these configuration settings:

```
    fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
    fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
```